# Phabricator web app - Add linting information

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

How to add lint information to a newly created revision in phabricator?

*arc* commandline tool can do this, but how could we the same through phabricator web app?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanic for adding lint information over the web at this time.